# Help regarding .uif and .cue .bin

Tags: 13.04, mount

I am facing difficulties loading or mounting .uif .cue .bin files on my Ubuntu 13.04 fully updated. Can somebody help? I have tried a few options by googling and experimenting on my desktop, it didn't work though :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try Furius ISO Mount.

> Furius ISO Mount is a simple application for mounting ISO, IMG, BIN,
>   MDF and NG image files even without burning them to disk.

To install, just click [**Furius ISO Mount** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/furiusisomount/)

<sup>Source:Ubuntu Apps</sup>

Comment: Does not mount .cue/.bin as requested by the OP.

Comment: It says so in the answer.  Also look [Here](https://launchpad.net/furiusisomount)